# Why does the same privilege unlock at different reputation levels on different sites?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

I am a part of many sites on the SE network, but the two I am referring to are Anime & Manga and Arqade. In A&M, I unlocked the ability to access review queues at 350 rep, while this privilege is not attainable in Arqade until 500 rep.

I've read some other questions, such as [Why do certain sites require more reputation for privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99553/why-do-certain-sites-require-more-reputation-for-privileges) that also address this, but they state that reputation levels differ when sites are still in beta. However, neither Arqade nor A&M is in beta (public or private) to the extent of my knowledge, so why do the reputation levels vary for the same privilege?

Comment: Somehow Anime & Manga seems to have kept beta privilege levels for everything despite having launched.

Comment: @RobertLongson Should I add the 'bug' tag to this question?

Comment: maybe [Design-Independent Graduation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263905/165773) Phase 2 hasn't yet started for these sites? I'd check respective [meta-tag:per-site-meta] for graduation related announcements to find out

Answer (score 5):

Seems that Anime & Manga graduated and began the design-independent graduation process [almost a year ago](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2594/congratulations-anime-manga-is-graduating). But if you read through the meta discussion on [Design-Independent Graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september) you will see that the increase in privilege thresholds is linked to the new design of the site:

> Privilege thresholds -- we know there was some [strong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260762/238110) [support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260763/238110) for raising them up front (in Phase 1). For now, we're rolling out design-independent graduation with **higher privilege levels linked to site design**.

And as you can see Anime & Manga has yet to receive a new design, hence no increase in privilege threshold. There is a [meta discussion](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2392/hey-listen-lets-have-a-talk-about-our-site-design-the-idea-gathering-2015-e) about the propsed design but I can't see anything regarding a timescale and I believe there has been a backlog on new site designs for some time.

Comment: If it does get increased to the standard privilege threshold, will I lose privileges that I previously had due to them requiring more reputation? Suppose I have 360 rep and I have a privilege that was unlocked at 350 rep; if this privilege was raised to be unlocked at 500 rep, would I maintain access to it or would I lose it and have to re-earn it?

Comment: It will be increased as soon as the graduation process is completed and I believe you [will need to re-earn privileges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139432/307988) (unless anything has changed, which I don't believe it has).