# Adapting privileges for low site activity

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

For sites like,

- [DevOps.SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/)
- [Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

Users can participate for seven months and not have enough reputation to edit a question or answer. The benchmark for editing a question should be whether or not you understand enough about a site and a community to exercise this power to make the site *better*.

The problem with these two sites is that for 2022, **NOT A SINGLE NEW USER** has gotten this privilege on either site. In fact, the most active users on both sites have not accumulated enough reputation to pass the threshold of editing a question.

- https://devops.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year (380 rep top yearly, 1000 rep to edit)
- https://android.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year (1,575 rep top yearly user, 2000 rep to edit)

Aside from the lack of activity on these sites, they feel rather dead. The content is subsequently unrefined as even people that *want* to edit things can't.

Not trying to single out either of these sites, but I'm not going to write a description to cut out a salutation or to fix formatting. If we're going to lower the bar for sites to get out of beta, I think it follows something should be done about these arbitrary limits. They're not attainable. And if anyone grinds on these sites for six months and can't edit questions, they're probably not going to find the experience enjoyable or stick around (and I would be curious to know if any data can quantify healthy community growth for either of these sites).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/282094), and specifically: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283224/282094 - levels are adjustable, but the *answer* is voting and not adjusting the levels for privileges; except for rare case, such as Wiki suggested edit approval.

Answer (score 8):

I agree there is a problem with these two sites, but we have to see what the community and mods think of the editing rep cap. I went on both sites to do some poking around, and found out the following:

DevOps:

- Serious voting problem (1 vote around every 5 questions or so)
- Questions asked per day is at or below 1

Android:

- Serious voting problem as well
- Questions asked per day is actually decently high (>5)

*Note these are vague calculations after sifting through the questions pages*

So for DevOps something has to been done about the entire community, it is falling apart. The participation level is too low. Android? While the question-asking activity is high, the voting problem is an issue.